# How can I properly shutdown Play (2.3.6) on windows?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.3

I'm running play on Windows 7 with the script generated via `activator stage`. The only way I can stop the process is via `taskkill /PID 1234 /F` which seems to abruptly abort it instead of giving Play the chance to shutdown properly. At least I cannot produce any console or log output in the `Global.onStop()` hook.

Omitting the `/F` option for `taskkill` doesn't work. It tell's me the process could not be stopped and I have to use the `/F` option. Is there any way to properly shutdown Play on Windows?

Comment: It's not focused on windows but I found this issue on github on this topic: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/1789 Seems like there is not much support for a graceful shutdown anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try `Control + D` to jump out of and exit the activator shell.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not running it from the shell but from the script generated via "activator stage".